# Convert SQL statement to Power BI DAX?

Tags: sql, dax

I have data imported in PowerBI and figured out a solution in SQL but need to convert it to DAX.
Here is the SQL Query:

```
 Select x.event_id, x. event_name, 
   y.event_id,y.event_name,x.attendees
   FROM events as x
   Cross JOIN events as y 
  JOIN attendees as att_x on x.id = att_x.id
   JOIN attendees as att_y on y.id = att_y.id
  WHERE(x.id <> y.id) AND (x.start < y.end) AND (y.start < x.end) and 
   (x.attendees = y.attendees)
   ORDER BY x.id,y.id
```

Comment: why not just make your query a view and then use that view as a datasource in powerbi?

Comment: You've asked us to take your sql query and convert it to dax, but you've supplied us with a screenshot of your sql code. Please copy and paste actual text. Use the code formatting button at the top of the editor to preserve whitespace and line feeds. Please don't make someone that is already going out of their way to do development work for you also have to transcribe a picture.

Comment: The data is imported from an online source straight into powerBI. I used SQL to come up with a solution but really need it work directly in PowerBI.